# Как обработать событие что в коллекции объектов (ObservableCollection) у объекта изменился реквизит

Tags: c#, wpf

Использую pattern MVVM + WPF, .Net Framework 4.0

Есть класс CustomItem

```
public class CustomItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private decimal? _amount;
        public decimal? Amount
        {
            get { return _amount; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _amount) return;
                _amount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Amount");                 
            }
        }

        public decimal? BalanceInStock { get; set; }
        public Guid Uid { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

В свою очередь он используется в ViewModel

```
public class SelectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CustomItem _selectCustomItem;
    private readonly ICardsRepository _cardsRepository;
    private readonly Guid _currentStockUid;

    public SelectionViewModel(ICardsRepository cardsRepository)
    {
        _cardsRepository = cardsRepository;
        _currentStockUid = ConnectionStrings.CurrentStockUid;
        UpdateItems();
    }

    private void UpdateItems()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>(SelectedCustomItems());
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }

    private IEnumerable<CustomItem> SelectedCustomItems()
    {
        return
            _cardsRepository.Flows.Where(s => s.Stock.uid == _currentStockUid && s.Status == 100)
                .OrderBy(s => s.NE.Code)
                .GroupBy(s => s.NE, s => s.Amount, (key, g) => new CustomItem
                {
                    Uid = key.uid,
                    Code = key.Code,
                    Name = key.Name,
                    Amount = null,
                    BalanceInStock = g.Sum()
                });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomItem> Items { get; private set; }

    public CustomItem SelectCustomItem
    {
        get { return _selectCustomItem; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectCustomItem)) return;
            _selectCustomItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectCustomItem");
        }
    }     

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Который в свою очередь создаётся и вызывается из MainViewModel

```
namespace ProductSelection
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly ICardsRepository _cardsRepository;

        private SelectionViewModel _selectionViewModel;
        private ShoppingCartViewModel _shoppingCartViewModel;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            if (_cardsRepository == null) _cardsRepository = new CardsRepository();

            ShoppingCartViewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel(_cardsRepository);
            SelectionViewModel = new SelectionViewModel(_cardsRepository);
        }

        public SelectionViewModel SelectionViewModel
        {
            get { return _selectionViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _selectionViewModel)) return;
                _selectionViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectionViewModel");
            }
        }

        public ShoppingCartViewModel ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            get { return _shoppingCartViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _shoppingCartViewModel)) return;
                _shoppingCartViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShoppingCartViewModel");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

В итоге получается форма подбора

[image: форма подбора]

Задача у меня следующая: в момент изменения количества в Items (ObservableCollection), необходимо обработать данное событие в MainViewModel и передать изменённый объект далее в ShoppingCartViewModel, но я не могу понять, каким образом обработать событие в коллекции объектов (ObservableCollection) у объекта CustomItem в момент изменения его реквизита.

Comment: Подождите, а кто меняет эти самые `Items`? `SelectionViewModel`? Ну так пусть и выставляет event наружу.

Comment: Вы не путаете случайно два события: изменении `ObservableCollection` (то есть, добавление или удаление элемента из неё), и изменении элемента, который _находится_ в этой самой `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @VladD Меня интересует как раз изменение элемента, вернее отловить событие изменения элемента, который находится в ObservableCollection, возможно необходимо использовать какую-то другую коллекцию?

Comment: @VladD Изменения Items обрабатывает SelectCustomItem, и данное изменение отловить не проблема.

Comment: Ну, можно при добавлении элемента в коллекцию подписываться на изменения, а при удалении отписываться. Коллекции, которая сделает это за вас, нет. Но мне кажется, у вас слишком сложный дизайн. Расскажите лучше вашу настоящую задачу.

Comment: @VladD Задача, состоит в реализации интерфейса подбора товара, и при изменении кол-ва, заполнении "корзины", на картинке это нижний Grid. Далее при нажатии на кнопку (которой пока нет), данные из "корзины", будут обрабатываться в неком документе, но это уходит за рамки данной задачи. Ещё раз акцентирую, что не стоит вопрос отлаживать изменения в коллекции по добавлению или изменению количества объектов в коллекции, а задача отловить изменения реквизита объекта в коллекции. По данному вопросу есть статья [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd252944.aspx) но я её не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс CustomItem должен наследовать INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class CustomItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal? _amount;
    public decimal? Amount
    {
       get { return _amount; }
       set
       {
           if (value == _amount) return;
           _amount = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged("Amount");                 
       }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Далее каждый элемент коллекции должен быть подписан на обработчик события PropertyChanged, т.е.

```
CustomItem item = new CustomItem();
item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
```

И задается логика для этого события

```
private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
// Ваш код
}
```

Таким  образом при изменении объекта класса CustomItem срабатывает событие PropertChanged, которое Вы и обрабатываете в item_PropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, решение вопроса, вынесенного в заголовок, — использование [`BindingList<CustomItem>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Поскольку `CustomItem` имплементирует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, то `BindingList` будет раздавать нотификации об изменении каждого элемента списка.

(Спасибо @Stack за наводку.)

---

Но мне кажется, вам просто нужно поменять дизайн на более правильный.

XAML, отображающий конкретный `CustomItem`, должен сам обрабатывать изменения в `CustomItem`'е автоматически, используя для этого `Binding`. Если элемент удаляется, это происходит не просто так, а по приходу какого-то действия пользователя. Вы должны навесить на это действие команду, и в VM-коде, обслуживающем эту команду (а) удалить элемент из `ObservableCollection<...>`, и (б) показать нужный диалог.

Таким образом, вам не нужно будет выяснять в VM, когда собственно `ObservableCollection<...>` поменялась, т. к. вы *сами* будете управлять этим.

Comment: _"BindingList будет раздавать нотификации об изменении каждого элемента списка. (Спасибо @Stack за наводку.)"_ -- пожалуйста. пример тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476702/196972

Comment: `BindingList` - это же из WinForms. Неужели в WPF оно тоже работает?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Оно из `System.ComponentModel`, так что не специфично для WinForms. Ну и поскольку каждый элемент в любом случае реализует INPC, то правильно прописанный XAML с Binding'ами будет получать данные непосредственно из элемента. А событие, да, будет рассылаться.