# Как обращаться к ObservableCollection и редактировать его?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот кусок кода, для уточнения происходящего. Тут я спарсил таблицу расписания с сайта, и не могу ее обработать, там надо ячейки с занятиями заменять на индексы (буквы) П и Л. Подскажите пожалуйста простой пример, с обработкой информации через ObservableCollection.

```
/// <summary>
/// Метод получение таблиц с расписанием
/// </summary>
/// <param name="facult">Передаем в метод ссылку на выбранный факультет</param>
/// <param name="groupNumber">передаем в метод ссылку на расписание выбранной группы</param>
private void GetDatafromSite(string facult, string groupNumber)
{
    HtmlWeb website = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = website.Load(string.Format("https://timetable.tusur.ru/faculties/{0}/groups/{1}", facult, groupNumber));

    // There are various options, set as needed
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

    // Use:  htmlDoc.LoadHtml(xmlString);  to load from a string (was htmlDoc.LoadXML(xmlString)
    // ParseErrors is an ArrayList containing any errors from the Load statement
    if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0) {
        // Handle any parse errors as required
    } else {
        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null) {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
            if (bodyNode != null) {
                // Парсим таблицу с расписанием по четным и не четным неделям
                var tables = bodyNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'table-lessons')]");

                this._firstWeekTimetable = new List<TimetableRowModel>();
                this._secondWeekTimetable = new List<TimetableRowModel>();

                this.ParseTable(this._firstWeekTimetable, tables.First());
                this.ParseTable(this._secondWeekTimetable, tables.Last());

                this._timetable = new ObservableCollection<TimetableRowModel>(this._firstWeekTimetable);

                if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() = >
                    {
                        this.SelectGroupStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        this.TimeTableStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        this.dgTimetable.DataContext = this._timetable;
                        this.btnOne.IsEnabled = true;
                        this.btnTwo.IsEnabled = true;
                        this.NameTiming.Content = string.Format("{1} -> гр. {0}", selectedGroup, selectedFacultFull);
                    }));
                } else {
                    this.SelectGroupStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    this.TimeTableStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    this.dgTimetable.DataContext = this._timetable;
                    this.btnOne.IsEnabled = true;
                    this.btnTwo.IsEnabled = true;
                }

                this.week = Week.Odd;
            }
        }
    }
}

private string TranslitWord(string word)
{
    return StringHelper.GetTranslit(word).ToUpper();
}

private void ParseTable(IList<TimetableRowModel> collection, HtmlNode table)
{
    var lessons = table.SelectNodes(".//tbody//tr");

    foreach(var lesson in lessons)
    {
        var model = new TimetableRowModel();
        var tds = lesson.SelectNodes(".//td|th");

        model.Time = tds[0].InnerText.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        model.Day1 = this.ParseDay(tds[1]);
        model.Day2 = this.ParseDay(tds[2]);
        model.Day3 = this.ParseDay(tds[3]);
        model.Day4 = this.ParseDay(tds[4]);
        model.Day5 = this.ParseDay(tds[5]);
        model.Day6 = this.ParseDay(tds[6]);

        collection.Add(model);
    }

    collection.Add(new TimetableRowModel
    {
        Day1 = string.Empty,
            Day2 = string.Empty,
            Day3 = string.Empty,
            Day4 = string.Empty,
            Day5 = string.Empty,
            Day6 = string.Empty
    });
}

private string ParseDay(HtmlNode td)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var forPrint = td.SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'for_print')]");

    if (forPrint != null) {
        result.AppendLine(forPrint.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'discipline')]").InnerText);

        result.AppendLine(forPrint.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'kind')]").InnerText);

        result.AppendLine(forPrint.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'auditoriums')]").InnerText);

        result.AppendLine(forPrint.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'group')]").InnerText);
    }

    return result.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Comment: ObservableCollection нужна если надо уведомлять, например, UI о том, что коллекция изменилась. просто привязываете ее к контролам. если в коллекцию добавить/убавить элементы, то UI обновится.

Comment: @Stack А как контролы привязать?

Comment: в конструкторе MainWindow.xaml.cs можно добавить `this.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();` а в MainWindow.xaml добавить `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />`

Comment: @VladD да, для них же и пишу программу

Comment: @maggotbrain: Тогда попросите их, чтобы они давали вам API, а не заставляли парсить вывод с сайта. Хотя, «за деньги клиента любой каприз», конечно.

Answer (score 2):

Если надо к DataGrid привязать список и свойства элементов этого списка, то вместо ObservableCollection надо использовать BindingList.
В примере DataGrid привязан к коллекции, а которую по таймеру добавляются элементы, и при этом у каждого элемента по своему таймеру меняется значение свойства. Все изменения выводятся в DataGrid.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Values" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            var c = new BindingList<Data>();
            this.DataContext = c;
            // по таймеру добавляем элементы в коллекцию
            var t = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
            t.Tick += (s, e) => {
                if (c.Count >= 10) t.Stop();
                c.Add(new Data());
            };
            t.Start();
        }
    }
    public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        System.Timers.Timer t;
        static Random r = new Random();
        public Data() {
            // по таймеру меняем значение свойства Value 
            t = new System.Timers.Timer() { Interval = r.Next(500, 1000) };
            t.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
                Value = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            };
            t.Start();
        }
        public long Value { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, `ObservableCollection` нужна для того, чтобы отображать данные, которые могут измениться в фоне. К тому, как именно вы обрабатываете входящую информацию, она не имеет никакого отношения.

Обычно `ObservableCollection` используют следующим образом. Во view размещают кого-то из потомков `ItemsControl` (например, `ListView`), прикрепляют `ObservableCollection` через `Binding` как `ItemsSource`, устанавливают свой `ItemTemplate`, который показывает, как будет отображаться каждый элемент списка. Теперь если кто-то поменяет данные в `ObservableCollection`, view автоматически подхватит это изменение.

Разумеется, наполнение `ObservableCollection` данными и поддержка их в актуальном состоянии лежит на программисте, то есть на вас.

Answer (score 0):

> простой пример, с обработкой информации через ObservableCollection.

Пример ObservableCollection, в которую добавляются новые элементы по таймеру.
Добавленные элементы выводятся в DataGrid.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            var c = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
            this.DataContext = c;
            var t = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
            t.Tick += (s, e) => c.Add(new Data() { Value = DateTime.Now.Ticks });
            t.Start();
        }
    }
    class Data  {
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```