# Ревью ReadOnlyCollection с уведомлением об изменении

Tags: c#, события, коллекции

Внутри класса имеется закрытая переменная списка, которая может меняться по логике класса. Имеется открытое свойство, предоставляющее элементы внутреннего списка только для чтения. Так-же мне требуется событие об изменении элемента внутреннего списка. То что мне нужно никак не связано с графическим интерфейсом. Это требуется для класса по управлению оборудованием. Вот два варианта, как я придумал сделать, но как правильнее я не знаю. Может в обще есть еще какие способы.

```
class TestClass1
{
    // Меняется внутри класса
    private bool[] _states;
    // Для чтения элементов массива _states извне.
    private ReadOnlyCollection<bool> _readOnlyStates;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<bool> States { get { return _readOnlyStates; } }
    // Событие, передающее индекс изменного элемента.
    public event Action<int> States1Changed;

    private void UpdateStates(int index, bool newValue)
    {
        if (_states[index] != newValue)
            _states[index] = newValue;
    }

    public TestClass1()
    {
        _states = new bool[20];
        _readOnlyStates = Array.AsReadOnly(_states);
    }
}
class TestClass2
{
    // Меняется внутри класса
    private ObservableCollection<bool> _states;
    // Для чтения элементов массива _states извне.
    private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<bool> _readOnlyStates;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<bool> States { get { return _readOnlyStates; } }
    // Для получения события об изменении сделать следующее
    // (States as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged

    private void UpdateStates(int index, bool newValue)
    {
        if (_states[index] != newValue)
            _states[index] = newValue;
    }

    public TestClass2()
    {
        _states = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
        _readOnlyStates = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<bool>(_states);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 1

Возникла надобность вот в таком списке, тоже не знаю как лучше поступить. Список хранит объекты с свойствами. Класс должен иметь возможность изменять свойства элементов и уведомлять об этом подписчика. Пользователь может только читать свойства элементов. Мне пришел в голову только вот такой вариант.

```
class ListItem
{
    public bool Property1 { get; private set; }
    public double Property2 { get; private set; }
    public ListItem(bool property1, double property2)
    {
        Property1 = property1;
        Property2 = property2;
    }
}
class TestClass
{
    private List<ListItem> _list;
    private ReadOnlyCollection<ListItem> _readOnlyList;

    public TestClass()
    {
        _list = new List<ListItem>();
        _readOnlyList = _list.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<ListItem> List
    {
        get { return _readOnlyList; }
    }
    public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;

    public void UpdateProperty1(int index, bool property1)
    {
        if (_list[index].Property1 != property1)
        {
            _list[index] = new ListItem(property1, _list[index].Property2);
            ListChanged(this,
               new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemChanged, index));
        }
    }
    public void UpdateProperty2(int index, double property2)
    {
        if (_list[index].Property2 != property2)
        {
            _list[index] = new ListItem(_list[index].Property1, property2);
            ListChanged(this,
               new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemChanged, index));
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Пришла в голову вот такая реализация. Пользователю открыт только `IMortarInfo` на чтение. Внутри имеется закрытая реализация этого интерфейса `MortarInfo` с возможностью редактирования. Так-же добавил `INotifyPropertyChanged` для упрощения написания кода с событиями. Из-за невозможности привести `IList<MortarInfo>` к `IList<IMortarInfo>` пришлось делать костыль.

```
public interface IMortarInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double Angle { get; }
    bool State { get; }
}
public class Mortars
{
    private class MortarInfo : NotifyPropertyChanged, IMortarInfo
    {
        private double _angle;
        private bool _state;
        public double Angle
        {
            get { return _angle; }
            set
            {
                if (_angle == value)
                    return;
                _angle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public bool State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                if (_state == value)
                    return;
                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MortarInfo() : this(0, false) { }
        public MortarInfo(double angle, bool state)
        {
            _angle = angle;
            _state = state;
        }
    }

    private readonly BindingList<MortarInfo> _mortarsInfo;
    private readonly List<IMortarInfo> _listForReadOnlyMortarsInfo;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<IMortarInfo> _readOnlyMortarsInfo;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<IMortarInfo> MortarsInfo
    {
        get { return _readOnlyMortarsInfo; }
    }
    public event ListChangedEventHandler MortarInfoChanged;

    public Mortars()
    {
        const int mortarsCount = 6;

        _mortarsInfo = new BindingList<MortarInfo>();
        _mortarsInfo.ListChanged += ListChanged;

        _listForReadOnlyMortarsInfo = new List<IMortarInfo>();
        _readOnlyMortarsInfo = _listForReadOnlyMortarsInfo.AsReadOnly();

        for (int i = 0; i < mortarsCount; i++)
            _mortarsInfo.Add(new MortarInfo());
    }

    private void ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                _listForReadOnlyMortarsInfo.Add(_mortarsInfo[e.NewIndex]);
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                _listForReadOnlyMortarsInfo.RemoveAt(e.NewIndex);
                break;
        }
        if (MortarInfoChanged != null)
            MortarInfoChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Так-же можно обойтись без костыля, но тогда при редактировании придется делать привидение типов.

```
public class Mortars
{
    private readonly BindingList<IMortarInfo> _mortarsInfo;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<IMortarInfo> _readOnlyMortarsInfo;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<IMortarInfo> MortarsInfo
    {
        get { return _readOnlyMortarsInfo; }
    }
    public event ListChangedEventHandler MortarInfoChanged
    {
        add { _mortarsInfo.ListChanged += value; }
        remove { _mortarsInfo.ListChanged -= value; }
    }

    public Mortars()
    {
        const int mortarsCount = 6;

        _mortarsInfo = new BindingList<IMortarInfo>();
        _readOnlyMortarsInfo = new ReadOnlyCollection<IMortarInfo>(_mortarsInfo);

        for (int i = 0; i < mortarsCount; i++)
            _mortarsInfo.Add(new MortarInfo());
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        (_mortarsInfo[2] as MortarInfo).State = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код на основе нового описания вопроса. Комменты взяты из текста вопроса.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

class Test {

    List<int> list = null;     // закрытая переменная списка

    public Test() {
        list = new List<int>();
    }

    // открытое свойство, предоставляющее элементы внутреннего списка только для чтения. 
    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> List
    {
        get { return list.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    // событие об изменении элемента внутреннего списка.
    public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged = delegate { };

    public void SetValue(int index, int v) {
        list[index] = v;
        this.ListChanged(this, 
           new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemChanged, index));
    }
}
```

`List.AsReadOnly()` - возвращает ReadOnlyCollection (является оберткой для List). Исходный код - [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,2b710ab0bc8866ad).

Comment: Ну в общем ты за мой первый вариант с небольшими поправками. Только я бы лучше `ReadOnlyCollection` сделал в виде закрытого поля, которое мы всегда возвращаем. Так не потребуется при каждом обращении генерировать объект, который потом будет убираться сборщиком. А вот твое событие мне больше нравится.

Comment: Я сделал дополнение к вопросу, интересно твое мнение

Comment: добавил в ответ о .AsReadOnly(). и еще: если объектов Test очень много, но мало памяти, то отдельное поле для ссылки на ReadOnlyCollection лучше не создавать -- т.к. поле занимает память,

Comment: _"Я сделал дополнение к вопросу"_ -- вижу. первое что надо переделать: сейчас в коде есть два вызова `_list[index].Property*` - т.е. два раза происходит выборка одного и того же элемента. если массив очень большой, а производительность критична, то лучше одну выбоку убрать так: `var v = _list[index]; v.Property*`

Comment: Там массив не большой. Меня больше интересует, что бы не было каждый раз вызова события.

Comment: _"что бы не было каждый раз вызова события"_ -- в методы UpdateProperty1 и UpdateProperty2 надо добавить `if(ListChanged != null) { тут остальной код, которые уже есть в методах }`

Comment: Мне тут в голову пришел еще один вариант, он вроде получше будет, но с своими костылями :-)

Comment: _"еще один вариант, он вроде получше будет"_ -- какой?

Comment: В самом низу. Update 2

Comment: @Nodon ок. значит вопрос закрыт?

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется отслеживать изменение свойств у элементов коллекции, то надо использовать `BindingList<T>` вместо `ObservableCollection<T>`.
Пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476702/196972).

UPDATE:

Пример для коллекции, которая состоит из чисел.
После привязки коллекции к DataGrid, изменение значений в коллекции выводится в DataGrid.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Values" Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            var c = new BindingList<long>(); // или ObservableCollection<long>();
            this.DataContext = c;
            c.Add(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            var t = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5) };
            var r = new Random();
            t.Tick += (s, e) => {
                if (c.Count >= 5)
                    c[r.Next(0, c.Count-1)] = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                else
                    c.Add(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            };
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня просто массив элементов типа `bool` к примеру, а не типов, реализующих `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: И я тут нагуглил `BindingList` вроде как не особо оптимизирован и лучше сделать наследника `ObservableCollection`, который будет обрабатывать события `PropertyChanged` у элементов. Вот тут есть реализации http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490533/notify-observablecollection-when-item-changes

Comment: @Nodon _"У меня просто массив элементов типа bool"_ -- добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: @Nodon _"BindingList вроде как не особо оптимизирован"_ -- не проверял, но можно посмотреть исходник BindingList -- [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/55afabf0a74c12cc.html).

Comment: Я перезадал там вопрос, тк понял, что в первый раз я написал какой-то сложно понимаемый поток сознания.

Comment: @Nodon добавил новый ответ