# Как использовать массив объектов в качестве источника данных в DataGrid в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть массив объектов класса `Supplier`, допустим это массив `suppliers` данных поставщиков. Как вывести этот массив в качестве таблицы в DataGrid в WPF? В WindowsForms это делается присваиванием

```
datagrid.datasource = suppliers;
```

В WPF у datagrid нету свойства datasource.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

В WPF коллекции отображаются через `ItemsSource`:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = suppliers;
```

Answer (score 2):

В xaml надо указать привязку

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

В коде

```
public MainWindow() {
    this.DataContext = GetSuppliers();
}

object GetSuppliers() {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("c" + i, typeof(string)));
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var r = dt.NewRow();
        for (var c = 0; c < size; c++)
            r[c] = "hello";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    return dt; // или вернуть массив/список объектов Supplier.
}
```

---

Другой пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476848/196972) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476670/196972).